# Combobox to textbox (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am pulling the data in the `TedaviAdi` column of string type from a table in the database to the combobox. When I select the data, I want the `TedaviAdi` selected in the textbox to transfer the data in the price column.

```
decimal value  =Convert.ToDecimal(context.Tedaviler
                                         .Where(x => x.TedaviAdi == (string)cmbTedavi.SelectedValue)
                                         .FirstOrDefault()
                                         .TedaviUcreti);
txtTedaviUcreti.Text = value.ToString();
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Could not cast object of type 'NetStok.Entities.Table.Treatment' to type 'System.String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void cmbTedavi_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Tedavi obj = cmbTedavi.SelectedItem as Tedavi;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            txtTedaviUcreti.Text = obj.TedaviUcreti.ToString();

        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```